# Adding new button on button click C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add a new customized button when clicking this (+) button. I have searched the internet a lot but found nothing. If anyone can help me I'll be great full, thank you in advance.

[image: Example]

Comment: Please, [try on your own](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Adding buttons to a form is a quite basic task.

Answer (score 0):

Write following code onclick Event of your button it quite simple task.

```
//Creating New Button                
Button btn = new Button();
//Adding Some text to button
btn.Text = "New Button";
//Specifing Location of Button to be placed
btn.Location = new Point(200, 200);
//Adding button to form 
this.Controls.Add(btn);
```

try above code.